# How to include supplemental packages in setup.py dependancy install

Tags: python, python-requests, setup.py

I want to use https with SSL via requests as a dependency to a python package I am designing. In order to run requests with https via ssl, it is necessary to run

```
pip install requests[security]
```

How would I include an equivalent of this call in setup.py so that when the user installs my package, the security packages are also installed?

Answer (score 0):

Any dependent packages must be installed separately.  You cannot have supplemental requests in your setup file, for security purposes the user must deliberately install each package.

You can, though, list the dependencies so users can see what is required.  The best way to do this would be in your setup file as such:

```
setup(name='myName',
      version='1.1',
      install_requires=['security'],
      # ...)
```

Here is the Python documentation on [Setup Requirements](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages)

Comment: I believe setup.py install will run install_requires. I'm just listing the dependences in here explicitly.